# pgsync cannot connect to Amazon PostgreSQL database on RDS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-rds, pgsync

I am trying to synchronize data from my local dev database to a test DB running on Amazon RDS using the `pgsync` gem.

My `.pgsync.yml` page is simple:

```
from: postgres://localhost:5432/imports_development?sslmode=require
to: [See attempts below]
exclude:
  - [A few tables]
```

I have tried many approaches but none of them are working. Here are all approaches and the error messages I've received:

```
to: postgres://awsuser:mypassword@imports-test.abcdefg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/postgres?sslca=config/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
  => invalid URI query parameter: "sslca"

to: postgres://awsuser:mypassword@imports-test.abcdefg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  => connection to server at "52.4.150.10", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "awsuser" does not exist

to: $(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL)
  => invalid URI parameter: "sslca"

to: imports-test.abcdefg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  => connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "imports-test.abcdefg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" does not exist
```

These are the credentials used by database.yml for the RDS database:

```
rds_db_name: postgres
rds_username: awsuser
rds_password: mypassword
rds_hostname: imports-test.abcdefg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
rds_port: 5432
```

I can connect to both databases with rails console, so it should just be a matter of getting the above statements right. What is missing here?

Comment: Have you tried `postgres://awsuser:mypassword@imports-test.abcdefg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/postgres` ?
Attempt no.2 seems to work, but doesn't include the DB name.

Comment: @FrederikSpang That was it! Please post an answer and I'll accept. I had to add `to_safe: true` to allow data to be overwritten on a non-localhost server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `postgres://awsuser:mypassword@imports-test.abcdefg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/postgres` ? Attempt no.2 seems to work, but doesn't include the DB name, based on the error.

Roughly the URI is in the format:

```
postgres://{USER}:{PASS}@{HOSTNAME}/{DBNAME}
```

The `?sslca=123` and other options AFTER `?` (the query string) is meant as options. Not all clients support all options here.